# Is it possible to upload videos from a Shared Drive from Google Drive to YouTube?

Tags: youtube, google-drive, google-shared-drive

My company has a Shared Drive on Google Drive, which we use so that everyone has equal access to various media we create. I have a whole pile of videos on the Shared Drive that we would like to make available to a group of customers. The cleanest way to do this seems to be to put them on YouTube, make a playlist, and send the customers the playlist link.  But I can't find a way to upload videos directly from a Shared Drive on Google Drive to YouTube. My Drive content can be imported, but not content on a Shared Drive.

Is there any way to accomplish this?  I would rather not have to download all the videos to my computer so that I can upload them to YouTube again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the official correct answer is that it is not possible to import videos to YouTube from a Shared Drive from Google Drive

Answer (score -1):

- go to your youtube account
- go to **Settings > Overview**
- under **Mobile uploads** copy your Youtube email address
- go to your Team Drive
- right-click on your video file
- select **Share**
- select **Email as Attachment**
- paste Youtube email address
- and click **Send**
- now go to Youtube and check your video manager

[image]

Comment: Oh yuck... what a horrible and cumbersome way to have to do it.  I will give it a shot but this is really clunky.  And I can't help but anticipate many hundreds-of-megabyte videos being rejected by the mail process... but I guess I'll find out!

Comment: I don't have any such Settings that I can find.  Where exactly in the Youtube UI is this located?

Comment: @JonathanvanClute https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W4oN6FtpGDc but it looks like this future was removed last year for majority users so maybe this will help: https://support.google.com/a/answer/6208224?hl=en&ref_topic=6248111

Comment: Ah ok, I don't have admin access so I'll ask the person who does and see where that gets us.  Thanks!

Comment: OK I now have unrestricted Youtube access, but I still can't find a way to directly publish videos from our Team drive, to Youtube.

Answer (score -1):

zapier can do it with the google drive to youtube zap. The issue Im having is that the Filename will upload as "unknown" which screws my SEO up

Answer (score -2):

There is an easy way available. Just go to [Google Photos](https://photos.google.com) and login with the same id which you use in Google Drive.
There you will find an `Upload` option. Click that, and then you'll get to upload files from either the computer or Google Drive. Just Click on Google Drive and your video will be imported in Google Photo.

Now log in to YouTube with the same login id and go to the upload page. There you'll find an option to `Import your videos from Google Photos`. Click the `Import` button and you will see the video which you wanted to import from Google Drive.

Comment: @marikamitsos Please don't use backticks for emphasis https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135112/inline-code-spans-should-not-be-used-for-emphasis-right/301372#301372

Comment: @JanDoggen I do not. They are **not** for emphasis. The backticks here _"...are computery "artifacts" that should be differentiated from expository text."_ [Inline Code Spans should not be used for emphasis, right?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135113)

Comment: This does not address my question which was uploading from a *team drive*, not uploading from standard Google Drive.

Answer (score -3):

There's an easy way on Android - I have a Google Pixel 7 and works great.

1. Log into YouTube
2. Go to the video you want to upload
3. Click the 3 dots and click 'send a copy'
4. Select the YouTube icon

That's all

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications SE. Team Drive was renamed to Shared Drive. You might want to consider this and include something like explaining how to find a video located on a  Shared Drive.